# How to implement hierarchical X-axis Bar chart in my angular JS application. The Bar should have +/- to open/close the hierarchical data like below

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, charts, bar-chart, echarts

[image]
Below is the image which has +/- for showing hierarchy

Comment: Good question. I think scaleBand / scaleLinear are not useable here, because expanded time periods make it non-linear. You will need to calculate bar positions manually

Comment: MichaelRovinsky so any open JS libraries for implementing this?

Comment: You can use d3 enter/exit pattern and a vertical scale, but manage collapse / expand and  X positioning of bars manually. I suppose it's a few dozen lines of code...

Comment: I suggest to google "Expandable timeline chart", and if you don't find anything suitable, I can try to help you later today...

Comment: Can we do this as grouped Bar chart using d3.js?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231215/discussion-between-michael-rovinsky-and-sharvani).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example of how it can work.

Aggregate your monthly data into quarters, then years.

Expand / Collapse bars with click.

Render only collapsed bars (expanded are replaced with their children).

```js
const months = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
    const value = 100 + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100); 
    months.push({year: Math.floor(i / 12) + 2018, month: i % 12, value, type: 'M', id: `M${i}`});
}

const quarters = months.reduce((all, month, index) => {
    if (index % 3 === 0)
    all.push({year: month.year, quarter: Math.floor(index / 3) % 4, months: [month], value: month.value, type: 'Q', id: `Q${index/3}`})
  else {
    all[all.length - 1].months.push(month);
    all[all.length - 1].value += month.value;
  }
  return all;  
}, []);

const years = quarters.reduce((all, quarter, index) => {
    if (index % 4 === 0)
    all.push({year: quarter.year, quarters: [quarter], value: quarter.value, type: 'Y', id: `Y${quarter.year}`});
  else {
    all[all.length - 1].quarters.push(quarter);
    all[all.length - 1].value += quarter.value;
  }
  return all;  
}, []);

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([2000, 0])
  .range([0, 150]);
const yAxis = d3
  .axisLeft(yScale);
  
const svg = d3.select('svg');
svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(50, 20)')
  .call(yAxis);
  
const container = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(100,170)')

const getQuarterBars = quarter => quarter.expanded ?
    [...quarter.months] : [quarter];

const getYearBars = year => year.expanded ?
    year.quarters.reduce((all, quarter) => 
    [...all, ...getQuarterBars(quarter)], []) :
    [year];
  
const getBars = () => years.reduce((all, year) => 
    [...all, ...getYearBars(year)], []);  
  
  
const barColors = {
    'Y': 'blue',
  'Q': 'green',
  'M': 'orange'
};  

const barText = d => {
    if (d.type === 'Y')
    return d.year;
    
  const QUARTERS = ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV']; 
  if (d.type === 'Q')
    return `${d.year}-${QUARTERS[d.quarter]}`;
  
  const MONTHS = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']; 
    return `${d.year}-${MONTHS[d.month]}`;
}
  
const drawBars = () => {
    const data = getBars();
  const allBars = container.selectAll('g.bar')
    .data(data, d => d.id);
    
  const newBars = allBars.enter()
    .append('g')
    .classed('bar', true)
    .style('cursor', 'pointer')
    .on('click', (e, d) => {
        console.log('CLICK: ', d);
      // If it's month, collapse back its quarter
      if (d.type === 'M') {
        const quarter = quarters.find(q => q.months.find(m => m.id === d.id));
        quarter.expanded = false;
      }
      else {
        years.forEach(y => {
          if (y.year !== d.year) 
            y.expanded = false;
        });
        quarters.forEach(q => {
            if (q.id !== d.id)
           q.expanded = false;
        });
            d.expanded = !d.expanded;
      }
      drawBars();
     });
    
  newBars.append('rect')
    .attr('x', -20)
    .attr('width', 40)
    .attr('y', d => yScale(d.value) - 150)
    .attr('height', d => 150 - yScale(d.value))
    .style('fill', d => barColors[d.type]);
    
  newBars.append('text')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 20)
    .style('font-size', '10px')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text(barText);
    
  const updatedBars = newBars.merge(allBars);
  updatedBars.attr('transform', (d,i) => `translate(${i * 50},0)`)
  
  allBars.exit().remove();
}  
  
console.log(years);
drawBars();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.6.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="200"></svg>
```